# How to use XDebug with VSCode on Vagrant (Homestead)?

Tags: php, vagrant, visual-studio-code, xdebug, homestead

Guide on how to setup XDebug on Vagrant (Homestead) with VSCode

Versions:

1. PHP 7.1
2. VSCode 1.16.1
3. XDebug 2.5.5
4. Vagrant 1.9.8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This guide is based on Vagrant (Homestead 6), PHP 7.1, Xdebug 2.55, VSCode. Homestead uses Ubuntu 16.04

1. Install [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html)
2. Add Homestead box to Vagrant. You can find more info about [Laravel Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/homestead)
3. Homestead folder has `after.sh`, copy these [LINES](https://gist.github.com/kmaxat/ce770e894d580017c71904220ea7590d) to after.sh to 
   install xdebug after initialization of vagrant.
4. Don't forget to specify `php: "7.1"` in `Homestead.yaml`at sites
5. Run `vagrant up` or `vagrant reload --provision`
6. If everything is correct, you should see this lines after `vagrant up` or `vagrant reload --provision`
   [image]
7. Install [VSCode](https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug) and  [PHPDebug extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/) **on local machine**
8. Open VSCode -> click "Debug" -> click "Configure or Fix 'launch.json'"
9. Use this [launch.json](https://gist.github.com/kmaxat/862bab781981233d32f53a6309e52f02) to setup PHPDebug extension.
10. Set breakpoint in any file, click on "Play" in debugger

Comment: Please update this answer, since the pointed launch.json uses deprecated syntax. The new syntax uses pathMappings https://github.com/felixfbecker/vscode-php-debug